# LINQ: Grouping By and Selecting from a List of objects based on max value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the MyItem class with 3 properties as below:

```
class MyItem
{
    private string _name;
    private int _value
    private DateTime _TimeStamp;

    public MyItem(string name, int value, string timeStamp)
    {
        this._name = name;
        this._value = value;
        this._timeStamp = DateTime.Parse(timeStamp);
    }

    public string Name
    { get {return this_name; } }

    public int Value
    { get {return this._value; } }

    public DateTime TimeStamp
    { get {return this._timeStamp; } }

    // ...
}
```

also I have a list of MyItem as below:

```
var myItems = new List<MyItem>() {
    new MyItem("A", 123, "23/02/2012"),
    new MyItem("A", 323, "22/02/2012"),
    new MyItem("B", 432, "23/02/2012"),
    new MyItem("B", 356, "22/02/2012"),
    // ...
}
```

how can I GROUP BY myList so that I am ONLY left with the items that have Maximum TimeStamp? ie the result below:

```
"A"  123  23/02/2012<br>

"B"  432  23/02/2012<br>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your code, I hope I haven't messed up your example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
myItems.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
       .Select(grp => grp.Aggregate((max, cur) => 
                            (max == null || cur.Date > max.Date) ? cur : max))
```

This will select your results in the fastest time possible (at least that I can figure) without creating new objects and iterating over the collection the least amount of times.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. In the even of records I have pulled from the database having matching dates and different values, I wanted to take the highest value. You rock man thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Select the Max from the Group:

```
from item in MyItems
group item by item.Name into grouped
let maxTimeStamp = grouped.Max(i => i.TimeStamp)
select grouped.First(i => i.TimeStamp == maxTimeStamp)
```

Comment: @ALIR.Bousari - You are correct.  The select statement of the query is creating a *new* `MyItem` and using an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) to set the properties.

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens - tnx for the clarification however as you can see from my recent edit above, my properties are getters only so can't set them here and I really don't want to be creating new objects.

Comment: @ALIR.Bousari - I see.  Well, then I'll undelete my answer.  It's more complicated than these which is why I deleted it, but it doesn't create new objects.

Comment: If you use 'select grouped.First(g=>g.TimeStamp==maxTimeStamp)' then no new items created.

Comment: @Phil & Joe Tuskan, Thanks guys, works great, any idea of the performance difference between this and Christopher's solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = myItems.Where(x => x.TimeStamp == myItems.Where(y => y.Name == x.Name).Max(z => z.TimeStamp)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: @ALIR.Bousari - While this answer produces the output you expected, it is a *very* slow algorithm: O(n^2).  I compared execution speed with @JoeTuskan's answer with this one, with *only* 1000 items in the list executing the query 5 times.  This answer took `00:00:15.8860736` while Joe's only took `00:00:00.0080155`.

Comment: @ Christopher, thank you for the analysis this will surely impact as the list gets larger (which is my case), I wasn't able to implement Joe's solution as I cannot understand the SELECT section

Comment: @ALIR.Bousari - Also, if there are multiple items in the collection that have the same values, it will return that item twice, instead of just once.  I don't *think* that's the behavior you want, but I suppose it might be.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp = select i from myItems
group i by i.Name into g
select new MyItem
{
    g.Name,
    Value = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp).First().Value,
    Timestamp = g.Max(x => x.Timestamp)
};
```

Comment: I've forgot the "into g". You need to learn linq if you want to use, mate.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I changed your class `MyItem` for some LINQ convenience (hope this doesn't cause problems) by adding a blank constructor to the class:

`public MyItem() { }`

In a sample console program, this code will work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myItems = new List<MyItem>() 
    {
        new MyItem("A", 123, "23/02/2012"),
        new MyItem("A", 323, "22/02/2012"),
        new MyItem("B", 432, "23/02/2012"),
        new MyItem("B", 356, "22/02/2012")
        // ...
    };

    var grouped = from m in myItems
                  group m by m.Name into g
                  let maxTimestamp = g.Max(t => t.TimeStamp)
                  select new MyItem
                  {
                      Name = g.Key,
                      Value = g.First(f => f.TimeStamp == maxTimestamp).Value,
                      TimeStamp = maxTimestamp
                  };
     foreach (var gItem in grouped)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(gItem.Name + ", " + gItem.Value + ", " + gItem.TimeStamp);
     }

     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output matches your expected results.